# Why was Evelyn so eager to rush the release of Joy?

Tags: resident-evil

In *Resident Evil* (2022), the CEO of Umbrella, Evelyn, is very insistent on an immediate release for the company's new drug, Joy, to the extent that she dismisses the concerns of Albert Wesker, the chief scientist, as well as various deaths caused by the drug during testing, and insists that it must be released immediately, without further research to resolve any issues it may have. This is, of course, the drug with "may start the zombie apocalypse" on its list of potential side effects.

Evelyn usually insists that she just wants to make a great deal of money, whatever the moral cost. However, while "starting the zombie apocalypse" might have been a very rare potential side effect of the drug,  its *primary*  effect *at intended doses* seems to have been to induce contentment and apathy to such an extent that potentially lethal accidental injuries would seem all but guaranteed, as in the case of Evelyn's wife. This does not seem like the profile of a successful commercial product. Still, perhaps Evelyn did not see it this way.

On the other hand, her statements about "changing the world," particularly when she loses her composure at the end when shooting Albert Wesker and when she talks about "finishing my grandfather's work," seem to suggest another possibility: she does not care about the commercial prospects of Joy, and instead views turning the world into blissed-out zombies, or *actual* zombies, as the end goal of her work.

So what were Evelyn's true motivations? Was Evelyn simply so eager to increase the company's profits that she undermined her own goal by trying to rush out a product with the potential for major consumer backlash? Or were the risks always precisely the point of Joy?

Comment: CEOs are always eager to rush the release of substandard products.

Comment: @Valorum - Come on, there's a little difference between "battery runs out quickly" or even "one in a thousand people will die" and "literally useless for the purpose advertised and will probably cause the rapid end of human civilization, but let's not wait two months to iron out the kinks." That's like Microsoft releasing Windows 12 two months ahead of schedule, except it actually only runs on Macs and might make your computer explode. Evelyn's decisions don't seem to make much sense from a pure business perspective, so I think the question of whether she has ulterior motives makes sense.

Comment: All three of those things sound like a marketing issue.

Comment: @Valorum - Note that when she knew the drug could literally turn people into zombies (bad PR if I have ever seen it), she was still on board with an early release, even before Albert told her that the quantities needed would (seemingly) be very high. I think almost any CEO who actually cared about their company's bottom line and had a clear view of things would take the extra two months to make sure that their drug did not *turn people into zombies*.

Comment: User Testing Dept's always overestimate the problems customers are going to have. That's why we have Customer Service.